# How does logging in interactively to a Windows host effect WMI queries to that host?

Tags: windows, wmi, wql

I have an application that performs WMI queries on remote hosts. I'm attempting to define the minimal amount of security permissions required for the user used to do the queries.

I've defined a user with minimal permissions. I've found that this user has enough permissions to do the needed queries, but only if the same user is logged in interactively on the remote host.

For example, if I log in to the remote host with the nonadmin user (i.e. open a desktop on the remote host), the query `select * from Win32_Environment` returns 2 additional entries than if I'm not logged in. The 2 entries are:

```
instance of Win32_Environment
{
    Caption = "COMP-BAF3244E\\nonadmin\\TEMP";
    Description = "COMP-BAF3244E\\nonadmin\\TEMP";
    Name = "TEMP";
    Status = "OK";
    SystemVariable = FALSE;
    UserName = "COMP-BAF3244E\\nonadmin";
    VariableValue = "%USERPROFILE%\\Local Settings\\Temp";
};
```

and

```
instance of Win32_Environment
{
    Caption = "COMP-BAF3244E\\nonadmin\\TMP";
    Description = "COMP-BAF3244E\\nonadmin\\TMP";
    Name = "TMP";
    Status = "OK";
    SystemVariable = FALSE;
    UserName = "COMP-BAF3244E\\nonadmin";
    VariableValue = "%USERPROFILE%\\Local Settings\\Temp";
};
```

as seen in MOF representation in the wbemtest tool. The wbemtest connection is to `\\remotehost\root\cimv2` as user `nonadmin`.

How does logging in to the remote host effect the results of the WMI query?

What permissions do I need to add to my user so that the additional information is available even when the remote user is not logged in?

Answer (score 0):

The problem has to do with the user profile not being loaded unless the user has the correct rights.

The user profile not being loaded is also an issue for calling Win32_Process.Create. If the profile is not loaded then this will fail with UNKNOWN FAILURE (8).

Thanks to [this blog post](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/alejacma/archive/2008/04/09/win32-process-create-fails-if-user-profile-is-not-loaded.aspx) for pointing out the cause of the errors!

In order to have the user profile loaded automatically while during remote WMI access, give the user "Backup files and directories" and "Restore files and directories" user rights.

You can find the these rights policies at:

`"Run..." --> secpol.msc --> Local Policies --> User Rights Assignment`